# Why does using Take() seem to speed up my EF query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a complex LINQ to EF query that was timing out.  While debugging I added a `Take(200)` and it did not time out.  What was strange is it only returned 127 rows!

In other words, adding the `Take` sped the query up *even though* it didn't change the results.  What could have caused that?

For clarification, the generated SQL was exactly the same except that with `Take(200)` EF added `TOP 200` to the `SELECT`.

Comment: Did you compared SQL generated from query with and without `Take(200)`?

Comment: well, you could check the generated sql

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro It adds `TOP 200` to the `SELECT` exactly like you would expect it to.  It makes no other changes.

Comment: Have you tried to execute generated SELECT from query without Take in SQL Management Studio? It does a timeout?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro In SSMS there's no speed difference.

Comment: @close voters - what's OT about the question?

Comment: Take both queries into SSMS and review the query execution plan. See what's different about the interpretation of the query.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that this change led the database to choose another query plan. As the DB new that at most 200 records would be returned, it has chosen an algorithm that was more appropriate for returning a small number of records (and 200 is small for a DB).

For instance using indexes does not always speed up a query. If you have less than (very roughly) 1000 records, the overhead involved, can actually slow down the query. Maybe the DB has chosen a simple table scan instead of a more complex query plan used before.

If you want to know exactly what happened, you will have to use the tools provided by your DB in order to analyze the query plans for the two variants. Unfortunately these query plans are not easy to understand, as they require quite a bit of in depth database knowledge.

In the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio you can call menu *Query* > *Display Esimated Execution Plan* from a query window.

Comment: Is there a way to compare the query plan's and verify if this is the case?  This is running against SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @just.another.programmer yesm look this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375126/why-does-using-take-seem-to-speed-up-my-ef-query?noredirect=1#comment56492179_34375126

Answer (score 2):

[There's a nice answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393508/sql-massive-performance-difference-using-select-top-x-even-when-x-is-much-higher) on why select top N is faster than a standard select even for the same size data set.  This is likely the speedup you are seeing.

Comment: Though the linked article may answer the question, it's better to quote the relevant parts here. The linked content may change or be deleted, but your answer should be useful to future so users as well.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thank you for the tip.